# LTspice- Huge current spikes across MOSFETs in full-bridge inverter

Tags: ltspice, inverter, full-bridge

I have designed a simple full bridge inverter in LTspice. The outputs for voltage and current are as expected however I have huge current spikes across the MOSFETs which I am using as switches and are controlled by PWM. Is there a reason for these spikes? Am I missing something from the circuit?

I have tried a number of different MOSFETs and diodes and increasing the resistance of the MOSFETs reduces the spikes but not by very much.

Here is the graphs I get from LTspice, Id(M1) is the current into mosfet 1 and Is(M1) is the current out, which you can see are far too high the other graphs show the current across the resistor and inductor of the load and the voltage out.

[image]

And here is my circuit

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not related to the current-spike issue, but this schematic is yet another instance of the classic problem of trying to drive high-side N-channel MOSFETs with ground-referenced signals that don't swing any higher than the main supply voltage.

Comment: @DaveTweed why is that a problem? I could increase the Vhi to increase the signal voltage above the supply value? Thanks.

Comment: The source cannot rise to a voltage greater than Vgate - Vthreshold. This is known as the source-follower configuration.

Answer (score 4):

The load is at least 5 ohms so, from a 10 volt supply it cannot take more than 2 amps and this just leaves how you are driving the MOSFETs. If you don't apply a little bit of "dead-time" when changing the PWM polarity you will get a phenomena called "shoot-through". This is because the MOSFETs don't immediately switch-off when disabling them and you can certainly get massive spikes of current when this happens.

Comment: ah I see, that makes sense, I will look into the best way of introducing dead time into the circuit, many thanks

Comment: another option is to  put an inductor before the h-bridge, that will reduce the current surge during the cross-conduction time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your current spikes are the charge and discharge currents of the mosfets parasitic caps in this case Coss. This happens when you are not implementing ZVS. Goggle Phase shifted full Bridge (ZVS).